# Why we pass 'this' in ko.computed

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am learning knockout from its official site and here is a tutorial which i taken from site

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = ko.observable('');
this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
}, this);
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I want to ask that what is the purpose of passing this as parameter to computed function

```
ko.computed(function() {
return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
}, this);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the **Managing ‘this’** section at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html? Is something still not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in Javascript **this** is most of the time not what you would expect it to be from a C#, C++ or Java Developer POV.

The this argument ensures that **this** is actually bound to the viewmodel when the new value of the computed observable is evaluated and not the this context of the calling method such as an event handler for example.

Comment: You can also bypass this by adding a "var self = this" as the first line of the ViewModel function. Then you refer to "self" everywhere you would normally refer to "this", including inside the computed functions.